# wicked_pdf on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, pdf-generation, production, wicked-pdf

Locally It works like magic but when I try to generate the PDF on the server it trows:

```
RuntimeError (Failed to execute:
"/path/to/my/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/wkhtmltopdf"       -q - - 
Error: Broken pipe):
```

Here's what's on **my_controller**.

```
format.pdf do
    pdf = render_to_string(
            :pdf => "invoice",
            :template => "my_controller/my_view.pdf.erb",
            :layout=>"pdf.html.erb"
        )
    save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs','invoice.pdf')
    File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
        file << pdf
    end
    send_file(save_path)
end
```

And in my **Gemfile**

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

Comment: Could you add the last part of your question as a answer and accept that as answer later? This will help others to understand what the status is ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fixed removing system installed `wkhtmltopdf` and using the binary of wkhtmltopdf:

1. Uninstall the wkhtmltopdf package: `apt-get remove wkhtmltopdf --purge`
2. (in usr/local/bin) `sudo curl -C - -O http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2`
3. (in usr/local/bin) `sudo tar -xvjf wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2`
4. (in usr/local/bin) `ln -s wkhtmltopdf-amd64 wkhtmltopdf`
5. In your initializer `WickedPdf.config = {
   :exe_path => "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
   }`

Comment: The download link is broken. Try this new link http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/obsolete/linux/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2

Comment: this installation needs to be done in local system? or its needs to be installed on AWS?

Comment: Vivek Sathisan left a comment as an answer: the source can be downloaded from https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/obsolete-downloads/releases

Answer (score 0):

For others experiencing this issue, we had the same error message with a different solution. We didn't have a headless browser running:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

solved it